# Dragging gesture in mid 2015 Macbook Pro with ForceTouch trackpad

Tags: macos, trackpad

I am trying to enable dragging to work both with 3 finger drag and double tap. In older Mid 2014 macs, the default was three finger drag and by enabling double tap we could have both features.

However in the new Macs I can't figure out how to enable both three finger drag and double tap at the same time.

I checked Universal Access Pref but when I select "three finger drag" the double tap dragging stops working.

I would like to have both for the mid 2015 Mac as well, as some users are used to three fingers and some to double tap. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to System Preferences > Accessibility

[image]

Comment: this will disable the double tap dragging in 2015 force touch macbook pro.